# How to escape exclamation mark from 'command' using FOR /F?

Tags: for-loop, cmd, escaping

How can I, with delayed expansion enabled, escape the exclamation mark inside of a command that is stated as an argument of a FOR /F command, like

```
set FOO=BAR
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem non-quoted variable
for /F %L in ('echo !FOO!') do echo %L
endlocal
```

or

```
set FOO=BAR
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem quoted variable
for /F %L in ('echo "!FOO!"') do echo %L
endlocal
```

to get `BAR` or `"BAR"` returned, respectively?
Unfortunately it is expanded to `!FOO!` or `"!FOO!"`.

When using immediate expansion (meaning `%FOO%` or `"%FOO%"`) I get what I want.

I tried to use `^!`, `^^!`, `!!`,..., also together with the "usebackq" option (`` `echo` ``), but no success.
Even preceding the first `echo` with a `call` command does not succeed.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the syntax used (`%L`) you are running it in the command line, and from this context the command `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` has no effect. If you read `setlocal /?` you will see this command is for batch files.

So, the real problem is that `!FOO!` is parsed as a literal as delayed expansion is not active (the default `cmd` configuration).

How to do it from command line? Enabling the delayed expansion for the `cmd` instance

```
set "FOO=bar"
cmd /v /c"for /F %L in ('echo !FOO!') do echo %L"
```

Note that the expansion of the `!FOO!` variable is done inside the `cmd /v /c` instance, not inside the `cmd` instance started to execute the `echo` command.

Comment: Yes, I was running it in the command interpreter; thank you for the hint concerning `SETLOCAL`!
I just found out that it works also with the first `echo` preceded with the `cmd /V /C` portion.

Comment: variant `cmd /V /C *` causes the command interpreter to carry out the command `echo BAR` when watching the echos; however, typing `cmd /V /C "for /F %L in ('echo ^^!FOO^^') do echo %L` carries out `echo !FOO!`, so expansion is done even later then.

Comment: @aschipfl, more or less, it is done inside the same cmd instance, but instead of to expand the variable before creating the new `cmd` instance to execute the inner `echo`, the expansion is done when the `echo %L` is executed. This is parsed and converted into `echo !FOO!`, and then, as delayed expansion is enabled, the content of the variable is echoed.

Comment: I understand, so the inner `echo` outputs `!FOO!` literally, which, after `%L` being substituted with that, is expanded to `BAR` by the last `echo`. This could be quite useful as there is the possibility to modify the variable `FOO` even in the body (`do()`) of the `for` statement. Hence, `(set FOO=BAR) & cmd /V /C "for /F %L in ('echo ^^!FOO^^!') do ((set FOO=MOD) & echo.%L)"` results in `MOD`, but with `^^!` replaced by `!`, the initial string `BAR` is returned.

Comment: @aschipfl, yes, in the `!FOO!` case the expansion is done when the `for` command is parsed. In the `^^!FOO^^!` case the expansion is done when the outer `echo` is executed.